# vertical align text on image

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I haven't been able to find a solution among the answers. I'm trying to center a text on an image, but I'm having some trouble with the vertical alignment. This is my code:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 main_category_container">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="wrap">
            <h3 class="sub_category_title"><a href="some link">Centered text</a></h3>
            <a href="some link"><img src="some image"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.wrap {
height:auto;
margin: auto;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
}

h3.sub_category_title {
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Right now the text is horizontally centered above the image, but I can't figure out how to vertically align it in the middle of the image.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Text and Image both have `href`. If you align heading vertically don't you think that this can cause confusion which element is for which link ?

Comment: They both point towards the same link. I've tried something similar with just a h3 without a link, but I thought that it was a bit confusing that you couldn't click directly on the text. Is there a better way to do it? I'm quite new at this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally if you're trying to put one element overlapping another, you'll end up using `position: absolute` or `position: relative` - otherwise, the contents will naturally arrange themselves in a block flow.

You could try something like this:

```css
.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  
  width: 300px; /* change or remove as needed */
  margin: auto;
}

.image-link { display: block; }

.image-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  
  /* The rest of this is just for this demo,
  you can change it for your situation. */
  
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <a class="image-link" href="#">
    <img class="image" src="http://loremflickr.com/300/200" alt="kitten!">
    <h3 class="image-text">A Centered Label</h3>
  </a>
</div>
```